# How to update a JSP recaptcha jar class

Tags: java, jsp, jar, recaptcha

I have downloaded the Java Jsp captcha jar file from here:
http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/detail?name=recaptcha4j-0.0.7.zip&can=2&q=

After much head scratching it appears this code is out of date, they have switched of the recaptcha.net domain in favour of google:
http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/wiki/FAQ#I%27m_getting_certificate_errors_for_api-secure.recaptcha.net

I can browse the jar file and inside ReCaptchaImple.java I see:

```
public static final String HTTP_SERVER = "http://api.recaptcha.net";    
public static final String HTTPS_SERVER = "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net";    
public static final String VERIFY_URL = "http://api-verify.recaptcha.net/verify";
```

I think it should be updated to something like this

```
public static final String HTTP_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
public static final String HTTPS_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
public static final String VERIFY_URL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";
```

The problem is, i'm not a Java developer and unsure how to go about editing the jar.  I've looked around stack overflow and into the winzip option, without making any changes to the code I have unzipped then rezipped and renamed from .zip to .jar but my new jar doesn't work - I get the following error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/tanesha/recaptcha/ReCaptchaFactory**

How do I update the jar file so that it points to the new servers?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So there is an updated jar file after all, you can find it here:

http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha4j/downloads/list

I've checked recaptcha4j-0.0.8.jar - the ReCaptchaImpl.class points to google server:

```
  public static final String HTTP_SERVER = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
  public static final String HTTPS_SERVER = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api";
  public static final String VERIFY_URL = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify";
```

Someone needs to update the Java documentation so that it points to the up-to-date code!

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/java